# What scope is $blog_url = get_bloginfo() inside a function

Tags: filters

Inside a plugin, I am attempting to filter the WordPress 'from' email name to a dynamic value instead of the default 'WordPress'.

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', function( $name ) {
    $domain_url = get_bloginfo( 'url' );
    return $domain_url;
});
```

This is not returning anything. I feel like it has something to do with scope.

Comment: Scope isn't your problem. How are you testing this?

Comment: I am uploading the plugin to the server, resetting the users password to have the server actually send an email out.

Comment: Would be interested in hearing a better way.

Comment: You need to eliminate the assumption that `get_bloginfo` is returning a valid value, and not an invalid value, or an empty value

Answer (score 0):

`$get_bloginfo()` function is root scoped.

For a measure of confidence, it's good to know it is used by the *wp_mail* function in the *pluggable.php* file.

```
// If we don't have a charset from the input headers
if ( !isset( $charset ) )
    $charset = get_bloginfo( 'charset' );
```

Comment: I am still not following.  Would anyone be willing to type out a function that would return the site url. I'd like to break it down to understand better.

Comment: You had it all along. It's  get_bloginfo( 'url' )